# Type guard not being identified when assigned to boolean - strict mode

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

The condition is the same in both typeguards, but only the second one works. I'd love to understand why?

```
export class MessageService {
  private _iframe?: HTMLIFrameElement;

  sendMessage() {
    const appLoaded = !!this._iframe?.contentWindow;

    // why does this not work?
    if (appLoaded) {
        this._iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({}, '*'); // ERROR
    }

    // while this does
    if(!!this._iframe?.contentWindow) {
        this._iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({}, '*');
    }
  }
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FlgZQc2AGVgoA3ASwWDgG8AoOOMKCslGGgfQoDMoUAW2AB%20AFxwAEgBUsAGQCSAMQHCAokmDCAdjADc9RnDTBtAExx5CACgCUdI0wQRtaeCjBg5EFGeBm4AF44AEIQmAALCjQAOh5%20IVEY511TGAB1CnMIAHcDRzgAekK4HIiATzgzCFw4SOi4bQh4HOgAaxECvjhrDy8fPzN7BiZR0frY%20NVgZJdOXUzsnJjIN0s0AmBrWgBfABo4AHIAKkPbAzGdwzHi0qjNOqjMatwu3mswibi%20aZFZ1IWWWqOWGBTGXymiX%208wyQNyKwga1wGxsuwOJzOF1GVyYVx2QA)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because TypeScript's flow analysis doesn't go that far. It doesn't track the fact that `appLoaded` being `true` also means that `this._iframe?.contentWindow` is also truthy. It's just a pragmatic limitation of the compiler. In theory, it could do it (until/unless you called a function after the assignment and before using `contentWindow`, at which point `this._iframe` and or `this._iframe.contentWindow` may have changed), but doing that is complex enough that it doesn't.

You could always do something like this, if you want to avoid repeating the condition:

```
const wnd = this._iframe?.contentWindow;
// ...
if (wnd) {
    wnd.postMessage({}, '*');
}
```